# Not fulfilling If condition but the function still return something

Tags: c++, function, if-statement, return, return-value

Below is the code :

#### The Code :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int sum(int ); //To sum up the user input up to 1 , for e.g 4 = 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 10

int main(void)
{
    int num;
    int total;

    cin >> num;
    total = sum(num);
    cout << total;
    return 0;
}

int sum(int num)
{
    if(num > 0) // How if num is -1 or -10??
        return num + sum(num - 1);
}
```

#### The Question :

1.) I try to execute the above code and input value that violate the if condition for e.g `-1` or `-100` . But still when I `cout` the `total` variable I get back the value I've given to the variable `num` .

2.) My question is , is this a standard behavior ? Because I can run this code without getting any warning or error saying there's no `return` statement stated I don't have an extra `return` statement in case the num is violating the condition . So is this *returning- the-original-value-if-the-condition-is-not-true* something normal or it depends on the compiler being used ?

THank you .

Comment: The function has to return something. Not returning anything when the return type is not `void` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @chris You meant "when the return type is `int`"?

Comment: @Fraser, I meant *not void*, thank you.

Comment: Do you have warnings enabled?  When I compile with g++ -Wall, I get: `main.cpp:22:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
`

Comment: yeah , that's my question . When i pass value like -1 or -2 to the function still i can get to run it and this function return back the original value num to the variable total

Comment: @VaughnCato Nope , not a single warning

Comment: It's one form of standard behaviour: _undefined behaviour_, it could crash, it could pretend to work, it could do anything, really.

Comment: @DanielFischer g++ 4.7.0

Comment: That's unexpected. gcc/g++ warns about that since ancient times with `-Wall`. If 4.7.0 doesn't, file a bug report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function that promises to return a value and does not induces **Undefined Behavior** (in C, only if the value is used).

Here your function has two executions paths:

```
int sum(int num) {
    if (sum > 0) 
        return num + sum(num - 1); // code path 1
    // code path 2
}
```

And in the second code path, it does not return anything.

Undefined behavior means anything can happen. The popular image is that daemons could start flying out of your nose. In practice, you are more likely to get a more or less random value depending on the implementation. Looks like in your case, for your compiler, this program and that set of optimizations (and maybe because the stars aligned, too) you get `num`. Lucky you.

By the way, [my compiler gives a warning](http://liveworkspace.org/code/cf69161560718e622ab6c062fc8e940e):

```
source.cpp: In function 'int sum(int)':
source.cpp:22:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```